# Get URL from HTTP Request node

Tags: ibm-integration-bus, extended-sql

My msgflow looks like:

**MQinput** -> **Compute node** -> **HTTP Request**

I have override.properties for DEV set to:

```
MsgflowName#HTTP Request.URLSpecifier = https://myDevUrl.com/id
```

and another 2 override.properties files for TEST and PROD:

```
MsgflowName#HTTP Request.URLSpecifier = https://myTestUrl.com/id
```

and

```
MsgflowName#HTTP Request.URLSpecifier = https://myProdUrl.com/id
```

but I want to pass URLs dynamicaly like https://myDevUrl.com/id/123, where 123 is id, which I get in request.

I know that I can use:

```
SET OutputLocalEnvironment.Destination.HTTP.RequestURL = https://myUrl.com/id/123
```

but for this command I don't know if that URL is for DEV, TEST or PROD.

I can resolve this by inserting URL for DEV/TEST/PROD to DB, but I'm looking for simpler way.

**So my question is:**

I there any way to get a URL from HTTP Request node (which is set in override.properties)

Something like:

```
SET URL = OutputLocalEnvironment.Destination.HTTP.RequestURL;  -- was not worked
```

**or**

is there any other workaround?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the [properties that are accessible from ESQL](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSMKHH_10.0.0/com.ibm.etools.mft.doc/ak04897_.htm), you have to go for the workaround.

Define a [User-Defined Property](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSMKHH_10.0.0/com.ibm.etools.mft.doc/ac00643_.htm) (UDP) in the overrides like this:

```
MsgflowName#TheURL = https://myDevUrl.com/id
```

[Access the UDP](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSMKHH_10.0.0/com.ibm.etools.mft.doc/ak01015_.htm) like this:

```
CREATE COMPUTE MODULE YourModule
  DECLARE TheURL EXTERNAL CHARACTER '';

  CREATE FUNCTION Main() RETURNS BOOLEAN
  BEGIN
    DECLARE idFromRequest CHARACTER ...;
    DECLARE url CHARACTER TheURL || '/' || idFromRequest;
    SET OutputLocalEnvironment.Destination.HTTP.RequestURL = url;
    ...
```

Comment: Looks like best solution for me, I will use it. Thanks :)

Comment: Btw. beware of "User defined attributes must either be given an initial value on the DECLARE statement or be given a value at deploy time" error after deploy. So TheURL definition should be at least `DECLARE TheURL EXTERNAL CHARACTER '';` while debugging.

Comment: @Pivoman ok, thanks for the feedback and I updated my answer.

Answer (score 3):

This is a variant on @Daniel Steinmann's answer. You need to decide on how solid and consistent your Broker naming convention and Target system URL naming conventions are, and if they can be **approached** **algorithmically**.

They also need to be stable enough that you aren't going to have issues with hardcoding things. Yes hardcoding is considered by many to be anathema to good coding practice but adding another point of failure by using a config DB introduces its own issues. The question I ask before deciding hardcoding isn't going to introduce unwarranted deploys is will this change in a year.

```
CREATE COMPUTE MODULE ComputeNode
CREATE FUNCTION Main() RETURNS BOOLEAN
BEGIN
    DECLARE UrlPattern CHAR 'https://target-XX/resource/';
    IF CONTAINS(BrokerName, 'DEV') THEN
        SET UrlPattern = REPLACE(UrlPattern, 'XX', 'dev');
    ELSEIF CONTAINS(BrokerName, 'TST') THEN
        SET UrlPattern = REPLACE(UrlPattern, 'XX', 'test');
    ELSEIF CONTAINS(BrokerName, 'PRD') THEN
        SET UrlPattern = REPLACE(UrlPattern, 'XX', '');
    END IF;

    SET OutputLocalEnvironment.Destination.HTTP.RequestURL =
        UrlPattern || InputRoot.JSON.Data.Aggregate.PrimaryKeyField;
    ....
```

I would note that most sites I've worked at will have a Config DB and if you don't have one it's quite likely you will in the not too distant future. Since the inception of the Callable Flow nodes I've started using them to have a single Callable Flow that handles loading the config data.

Best of luck with your solution.

Comment: Hardcoding is possible for this scenario too, but I will better use Daniels solution. We are using DB query for URLs for only one application, but I don't want to create new table and I don't like much the dependency on database. Anyway thank you for  nice advice.